# What's a correct regex for grabbing account numbers ranging from 3 to 7 digits? Using in GTM. Would it be: ^(\d{3-7})$ Thanks

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Looking for the correct regex range to use in Google Tag Manager JS custom variable code.How do I match a range of 3 to 7 digits (meaning also everything in between)? Would it be:
`^(\d{3-7})$`

Thanks

Looked at individual regex examples including on stack overflow but not seeing this exact example listed. I've tried using separate code but realized the error I made in the code (why it didn't work as I had hoped).

Would it be:
`^(\d{3-7})$`

I expect the output to include every account number with `3, 4, 5, 6, 7` digits.

Answer (score 0):

You are close, and you may try this pattern:

```
^\d{3,7}$
```

A range (closed on both ends) for a given character or class is denoted using commas, not dashes.

Comment: Great thank you, this did work. Thanks for the assist!